# Is it safe to use extremely diluted H2O2 (< 0.1%) On eyes regularly?

Tags: eye, hydrogen-peroxide, melanin, diluting

According to this [study](http://ec.europa.eu/health/ph_risk/committees/04_sccp/docs/sccp_o_122.pdf):

***In 10 human volunteers, the threshold of detection for irritation was about 0.1% when hydrogen peroxide was administered as drops directly to the eye (McNally, 1990).***

Hydrogen peroxide reacts with Melanin pigments and turns it into colorless compound. Melanin is found in hair, skin and eye.
H2o2 is already used to bleach hair to lighten it's color due to its effect on Melanin.
this has already been many researches about turning melanin into colorless compound with h2o2 like [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2165063), and there exist commercial compounds for achieving this result on hair.
The question is why the same can't be done with eyes using extremely diluted h2o2 for long period of time.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE :-). You cite a study for your first claim, however for the effects of lightening the eye colour you just say "it is known". I have never heard of this effect and it is a very strong claim. Can you [edit] your question to include a study for that as well? What's more, the source you cite refers to more that one study, in fact the same author (McNally) found that a different mode of administration of H2O2 (via soaking contact lenses) has a much lower threshold of irritation.

Comment: I clarified the question .. acutally h2o2 is already used in hair bleaching due to its effect on melanin that's what I really meant when I said it is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [study regarding hydrogen peroxide and human cataract](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0014-4835(81)80107-8), hydrogen peroxide was shown to damage the proteins in the human lens, thereby leading to the formation of cataract **(Spector and Garner, 1981)**. Using hydrogen peroxide for the eyes will probably result into eye damage.